# React re-render after login -- and after an asynchronous call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, axios

In my `Login` react component here, I call `handleLogin` within the `handleSubmit` method.  And then... (see below)...

```
import React from "react"
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom"
import axios from 'axios'
import Form from "./Form"
import View from "./View"
import { handleLogin, isLoggedIn } from "../utils/auth"

export default class Login extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      email: ``,
      password: ``,
    };
  }

  handleUpdate(event) {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
    })
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    handleLogin(this.state)
  }

  render() {
    if (isLoggedIn()) {
      return <Redirect to={{ pathname: `/app/profile` }} />
    }

    return (
      <View title="Log In">
        <Form
          handleUpdate={e => this.handleUpdate(e)}
          handleSubmit={e => this.handleSubmit(e)}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

...Within the `handleLogin` method (imported from `../utils/auth` below), I make an asynchronous call (`axios.post`):

```
// in /utils/auth.js

import axios from 'axios'

const isBrowser = typeof window !== `undefined`

const getUser = () =>
  window.localStorage.gatsbyUser
    ? JSON.parse(window.localStorage.gatsbyUser)
    : {}

const setUser = user => (window.localStorage.gatsbyUser = 
JSON.stringify(user))

export const handleLogin = ({ email, password }) => {
  if (!isBrowser) return false

  axios.post(`${process.env.API_URL}/sessions`, {
    email: email,
    password: password,
  })
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response);
    return setUser({
      name: `Jim`,
      legalName: `James K. User`,
      email: email,
    })
  })
  .catch(error => {
    return false
  });
}

export const isLoggedIn = () => {
  if (!isBrowser) return false

  const user = getUser()
  return !!user.email
}
```

The problem I run into is that the `render()` method is called before the `axios.post / handleLogin(this.state)` is resolved, thus preventing the `render()` method from seeing the `isLoggedIn()` as returning `true`.

I'd like to know how I can prevent the `render()` method from being called before `axios.post` is resolved.

Comment: This kind of functionality should be handled by higher ordered components if you truly want the React way of doing things. That way, you can 'prevent' the render method from being called. Secondly, the login state (get it?!) of your app should/can be stored in state, and accessed by all children components (which in this case will be basically your entire app).

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this problem by triggering a re-render. Based on your code example, I reckon you just need to wait for the `handleLogin` async call to finish, then check if user is logged or not with `isUserLogin`, you should add a local state that is mirrored `isUserLogin` to trigger the re-render.

Below is an example using Promise, you can achieve the same thing with async/await:

```
export default class Login extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      email: ``,
      password: ``,
      isLoggedIn: false
    };
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    handleLogin(this.state)
      .then(response => this.setState({isLoggedIn: isLoggedIn()}))
      .catch(err => // Handle the error here, or just swallow it)
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.isLoggedIn) {
      return <Redirect to={{ pathname: `/app/profile` }} />
    }

    return (
      <View title="Log In">
        <Form
          handleUpdate={e => this.handleUpdate(e)}
          handleSubmit={e => this.handleSubmit(e)}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: When I tried this, `handleLogin(this.state)` returns `undefined`, thus I get a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` error -- even after I'd added `.then(response => {return isLoggedIn()})` to the `handleLogin` method.  The asynchronous call in `handleLogin` does not resolve in time to provide a return value when it is invoked in `handleSubmit`.

Comment: @matt, it is a problem with your `handleLogin` function. Basically, by the time the then response is running, the `handleLogin` must be already resolved. The problem is you return nothing from your `handleLogin` function, so it's return type is undefined. You should update it to return the `axios` function: `return axios.post(...)`

Comment: I see that adding `return` to `axios` enables `handleLogin(this.state)` to return.  Thanks!